# preg_match issue (not parsing as I expected)

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm parsing a mail header, and I'm looking for the "boundary=..." parameter.

```
$content = '..Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_000_10CD_01CD3CB2.7C22E7C0"
X-Mailer: Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000..'
```

I'm using the following, but none of them works:

```
    $boundary = preg_replace('#(.*)boundary="(.*)"(.*)#is',"$2",$content);

    $boundary = preg_replace('#boundary="(.*)"#i',"$2",$content);
```

The first line returns:

```
NextPart_000_10CD_01CD3CB2.7C22E7C0"
X-Mailer: Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000
```

While the second one:

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    ----=_NextPart_000_10CD_01CD3CB2.7C22E7C0
X-Mailer: Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000
```

I understand what the second lines does, and it do it correctly. But I don't get while the first line doesn't parse the second double quotes. Any idea?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do, match using preg_match or replace using preg_replace? You're mixing it up.

Comment: I'm not really using it for replacing, but instead for matching I guess

Comment: Your question really made me realized I had to use preg_match, my bad: preg_match('#boundary="(.*)"#i',$content,$m);

Comment: So what exactly is not working here? It seems to match just fine

Comment: Have you already thought of using already existing libraries like [Mailparse](http://php.net/book.mailparse) to do this?

Comment: knowing about mailparse some time ago would have helped me actually a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/boundary="([^"]+)"/m', $content, $m);
echo $m[1]; // ----=_NextPart_000_10CD_01CD3CB2.7C22E7C0
```

Answer (score 0):

I could finally solve it using the negative matcher [^"]*

```
$boundary = preg_replace('#(.*)boundary="([^"]*)(.*)#is',"$2",$content);
```

But still if anyone knows the answer to my question, it would be appreciated. I don't fully understand the behavior of (.*) used with s modifier

Answer (score 0):

in response to your question in your self-answer:

`.*`, when used with the `s` modifier, also includes newlines iirc.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

> s (PCRE_DOTALL)
>
> If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character, independent of the setting of this modifier.